# Exception in AuthenticationMiddleware causes exception in ExceptionHandlerMiddleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

In my AuthenticationHandler class in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app, I am trying to request a token from another ASP.NET Core 3.1 which I setup to be a token distributor. I wanted to know what would happen if the token distributor happened to be offline. Of course, this caused an `HttpRequestException` to occur.

However I have also setup an ExceptionHandler by using
`app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");`

At the receiving end is an ErrorController with the following code:

```
    [ApiController]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public class ErrorController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("/error")]
        public IActionResult ErrorLocalDevelopment(
            [FromServices] IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

But nevermind that, because the action is not even called. It seems that an exception is occuring inside the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware, preventing the action from being called.
It keeps rethrowing the `HttpRequestException` with a few extra lines.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (61): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 245
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at [ProjectName].Assemblers.ApiKeyAssembler.GetApiKey(String key) in [ProjectPath]ApiKeyAssembler.cs:line 23
   at [ProjectName].Authentication.ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() in [ProjectPath]ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]
      An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (61): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 245
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at [ProjectName].Assemblers.ApiKeyAssembler.GetApiKey(String key) in [ProjectPath]ApiKeyAssembler.cs:line 23
   at [ProjectName].Authentication.ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() in [ProjectPath]ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM1UM7U89F38", Request id "0HM1UM7U89F38:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (61): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 245
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at [ProjectName].Assemblers.ApiKeyAssembler.GetApiKey(String key) in [ProjectPath]ApiKeyAssembler.cs:line 23
   at [ProjectName].Authentication.ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() in [ProjectPath]ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 1156.4184ms 500
```

The call `ApiKeyAssembler.GetApiKey(String key)` is a Refit call to our token distributor service, which as said before, isn't online.

I've been going on for hours but I just cannot find any solution.

EDIT:

I figured out what's going on in more detail. This happens when an exception occurs while the ExceptionHandler is trying to reach it's destination. Apparently when trying to reach the ErrorController, the AuthenticationHandler is run again, which is the very thing that's causing the exception in the first place. I however can't seem to figure out how to stop this from happening when trying to reach actions that don't need authentication.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @IanKemp I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1

Comment: can you share screenshot of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my exception handler route and your last edit helped point me in the right direction. Try using the [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the ErrorController action.

Comment: Oh my. I solved it that way as well but I forgot to update this post. I'll accept your answer since it does turn out to be correct.